# On Windows, how can I find what files a given process is using? Is there software that does this?

Tags: windows

I want to know the files a given process is reading/writing. Is there a program that shows this? On Windows XP. Thanks. I've tried Autohotkey Spy, Spy++, and Process Explorer. They show a lot of detail but not which files are being accessed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx)

> Process Monitor is an advanced
>   monitoring tool for Windows that shows
>   real-time file system, Registry and
>   process/thread activity. It combines
>   the features of two legacy
>   Sysinternals utilities, Filemon and
>   Regmon, and adds an extensive list of
>   enhancements

Comment: I am using process monitor right now... but I don't seem to find where you can see the opened files...

Comment: view->lower_pane_view->Handles
Takes a bit to populate with open files (that's why I didn't see it before.)

Answer (score 2):

[Filemon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896642.aspx)

Comment: While Filemon does the job, it is no longer maintained and has been replaced by Process Monitor: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx